# Is Mapei ceramic tile mortar compatible with mapelastic Aquadefense?

Tags: shower, tiling

These two products:

https://mapeihome.com/lowes/product/ceramic-tile-mortar/

[https://mapeihome.com/flooranddecor/product/mapelastic-aquadefense/#:~:text=Mapelastic%20AquaDefense%20dries%20after%20about,liner%2C%20and%20exceeds%20ANSI%20A118](https://mapeihome.com/flooranddecor/product/mapelastic-aquadefense/#:%7E:text=Mapelastic%20AquaDefense%20dries%20after%20about,liner%2C%20and%20exceeds%20ANSI%20A118).

​

Will they work with eachother for a shower with ceramic subway tile?

​The aquadefense says that it is for thinset mortar, which is what the Maplei is, but on Maplei's own site, they recommend different products to go with each of these.

Are they compatible even though they aren't quite to Maplei's recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: You need to check with the manufacturer.  If Maplei won't say they are campatible, I doubt anyone here will.

Comment: I've found Mapei customer support to be responsive & helpful. Call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AquaDefense works with polymer and epoxy mortars. That thinset is a polymer mortar, so the two products are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I have use the Ultraflex and the Keraflex over AquaDefense with great results.

If they don't approve of the ceramic tile mortar, use the [Ultraflex-1](https://www.lowes.com/pd/MAPEI-UltraFlex-1-50-lb-White-Thinset-Tile-Mortar/5014029391?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-flr-_-ggl-_-LIA_FLR_244_Tools-Setting-Materials-Access-_-5014029391-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwxaanBhBQEiwA84TVXLrqDVGbLt6ahFFmRR8cg-o1eYoGn1qDb8Mk9dgzOpKAfLi2laef0RoCCxcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

( I don't see the straight Ceramic Tile Mortar available in my area)